# getting js radio buttons to have multiple selections instead of a single selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am new to javascript and i am trying to make a website where you can purchase sandwiches however it is a prototype site that wont be published. so far i have this code for javascript:

Code:

```js
function selectmeat2(id) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked = false;
  }
  document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```

```html
<h3>Meat 2 (Optional - Extra £1.50)</h3>
Pepperoni<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="pepperoni" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="pepperoni" /><br> Sausage
<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="sausage" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="sausage" /><br> Jerk Chicken<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="jerk chicken" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="jerk chicken" /><br> Chorizo
<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="chorizo" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="chorizo" /><br> Bacon
<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="bacon" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="bacon" /><br> Steak
<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="steak" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="steak" /><br> Meatballs
<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="meatballs" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="meatballs" /><br> Pepperoni
<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="pepperoni" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="pepperoni" /><br> Ham
<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="ham" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="ham" /><br> BBQ Beef<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="bbq beef" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="bbq beef" /><br> Tuna
<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="tuna" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="tuna" /><br> Plain Chicken<input type="radio" name="meat2" value="plain chicken" onclick="selectmeat2(id)" id="plain chicken" /><br>
<hr>
```

So far i have it working for stuff such as collection or delivery as its only one choice. But i am trying to make it so the user can choose 4 or less from the meats available. i am really not sure where i am going wrong, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Whoops. As Ibrahim pointed out. All you need to do is have different name="..." tags.

You can only select a single meat2. I'm not sure how you'd limit to just four.

Comment: @htr5 It's quiet the opposite I think.

Comment: I did have them as a checkbox at first so I might just switch them back. Do you know if I can assign values (i.e. Prices) using js to the radio buttons and the checklist buttons if they are all one one webpage?

Comment: You have an error here `onclick="selectmeat2(id)"`. `id` is `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, you can! Read about `data` attributes! Here is a [**start**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). Yours will be `data-price`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using checkboxes in this situation.

Checkboxes are used when multiple options can be selected.

Radio buttons are used when one option out of a group of options can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

As @KyleRichardson says, use checkboxes, not radio buttons.

Assume :

- the group of "Meat" checkboxes is in a container with `id="meats"`.
- the click handlers are attached in javascript, not in the HTML.

```
var $meatsInput = $("#meats input"),
    maxMeats = 4;
$meatsInput.on('click', function() {
    // Count up the number of checked checkboxes
    var n = $meatsInput.get().reduce(function(n, el) {
        return n + el.checked;
    }, 0);
    // If the maximum is reached, then disable all other checkboxes to prevent their selection.
    // By leaving the checked checkboxes enabled, they can be unchecked.
    $meatsInput.get().forEach(function(el) {
        el.disabled = n >= maxMeats && !el.checked;
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s32anxxo/1/)**

There's no need to use `id` in the function, because it addresses all checkboxes in the group at every call, regardless of which one was actually clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I made this alternative for you. change the name of the input so you can select multiples meat.

```js
var maxMeats = 4;
var currentMeats = [];

function selectMeat(id) {
  var index = currentMeats.indexOf(id)
  document.getElementById(id).checked = false;

  if (index > -1) {
    currentMeats.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    if (currentMeats.length < maxMeats) {
      currentMeats.push(id);
      document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
    } else {
      alert('You can choose 4 or less from the available meats.');
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('meats').innerHTML = currentMeats.join('</br>');
}
```

```html
<h3>Meat 2 (Optional - Extra £1.50)</h3>
Pepperoni<input type="radio" name="pepperoni" value="pepperoni" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="pepperoni" /><br> Sausage <input type="radio" name="sausage" value="sausage" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="sausage" /><br> Jerk Chicken<input type="radio" name="jerk_chicken"
  value="jerk_chicken" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="jerk_chicken" /><br> Chorizo
<input type="radio" name="chorizo" value="chorizo" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="chorizo" /><br> Bacon
<input type="radio" name="bacon" value="bacon" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="bacon" /><br> Steak
<input type="radio" name="steak" value="steak" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="steak" /><br> Meatballs
<input type="radio" name="meatballs" value="meatballs" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="meatballs" /><br> Ham
<input type="radio" name="ham" value="ham" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="ham" /><br> BBQ Beef<input type="radio" name="bbq_beef" value="bbq_beef" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="bbq_beef" /><br> Tuna
<input type="radio" name="tuna" value="tuna" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="tuna" /><br> Plain Chicken<input type="radio" name="plain_chicken" value="plain_chicken" onclick="selectMeat(id)" id="plain_chicken" /><br>
<hr>

<div id="meats"></div>
```